# Node.js POST method error 404

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, http-status-code-404, vuetify.js

I built an index.js file which sends SMS based on body input while posting with Postman. The code is working and looks like this (I have hidden my apiKey and apiSecret for this preview)

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const Nexmo = require('nexmo');
const nexmo = new Nexmo({
   apiKey: 'hidden.apiKey',
   apiSecret: 'hidden.apiSecret'
   });

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
// Sending SMS via Nexmo
nexmo.message.sendSms(
    '4542542445', req.body.toNumber, req.body.message, {type: 'unicode'},
  (err, responseData) => {if (responseData) {console.log(responseData)}}
);
}); 
const server = app.listen(3000);
console.log("starting server")
```

It woks fine and I receive an SMS message when I run the file, and a post to the route using Postman.

I am trying to implement the same in my bigger project, where I have separate client and server folders representing my frontend and backend.

When I add the code to my app.js file, I run into Status code 404 not found error. Here is the code of my app.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const {sequelize} = require('./models')
const config = require('./config/config')
const Nexmo = require('nexmo')

const app = express()

app.use(morgan('combined'))

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}))

app.use(cors())

require('./routes')(app)

sequelize.sync()
.then(() => {
    app.listen(config.port)
    console.log(`Server started on port ${config.port}`)
})

const nexmo = new Nexmo({
apiKey: 'hidden.apiKey',
apiSecret: 'hidden.apiSecret'
}, {debug: true})

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
// Sending SMS via Nexmo
nexmo.message.sendSms(
    '4542542445', req.body.toNumber, req.body.message, {type: 'unicode'},
  (err, responseData) => {if (responseData) {console.log(responseData)}}
);
  });
```

I am asking for help to try figure out what is wrong and why it does not hit the route, instead returning status code 404.

I can share my github or we can talk on discord: soko#8667

I appreciate your thoughts and help.

Comment: looks like your app start when this function is ok : `sequelize.sync()`. does your app even starts ?

Comment: my current app works perfectly, without any issues. When I add nexmo message route it does not seem to hit the route somehow

Comment: what is this line `require('./routes')(app)` for ?

Comment: I have my routes in an external .js file, it simply requires it so I don't have my app.js filled with routes

Answer (score 0):

Routes in express should be written :

```
let route =  require('routes');
app.use('/', route);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work.

I was adding new route while my server was running.

I restarted my PC and ran server and client again and it seems work.

Comment: why don't you try using `nodemon` to automate changes like this? It will save you the stress of having to restart your server

Comment: Well I am using nodemon and that is why I had no clue why it wasn't working (the new route). I was expecting nodemon to do it but I guess it was different with open port.